# Custom Post type description is not showing

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a WordPress theme, where I want to use CPT UI with texonomy. There I want to show texonomy name, link, thumbnail of this texonomy and description.

All are working except description. Here is my coding:

```
<div class="catagory-section" id="know-desti">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="heading">
                <strong>Know Your</strong> <span>Destination</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 category-listing">



<?php foreach (get_terms('destination') as $cat) : ?>

<div class="row margin-bottom-10">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 padding-0 post-listing">
                    <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" class="cate-img" />
                        <h2 class="cate-heading margin-0"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2>
                        <p><?php _ex($description = term_description( $term_id, $taxonomy )); ?></p>

                        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'destination'); ?>" class="cate-button">Know More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="stone-img"></div>
```

Why is my description not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
$taxonomy ='custom_taxonomy_type'; {like: product_cat}
echo term_description( $term_id, $taxonomy )
```